# script for mounting an iso on another server

Tags: python

i need to mount a iso on another linux system

is there any way to send mount command to the linux system?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

SSH seems to be your best bet. Although I have never used it, http://commandline.org.uk/python/sftp-python-really-simple-ssh/ seems to be a good option.

```
import ssh
s = ssh.Connection('[Target Machine]')
s.execute('mount -o loop [ISO File] [Mount Point]')
s.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['ssh', 'user@host', 'mount', '-o', 'loop', '-t', 'iso9660', '<isofilename>', '<mountpoint>'])
```